# Google script - Can't attach a PNG file from Google Drive to form email

Tags: google-apps-script, jscript

I've setup a trigger with the following code to send out an email everytime an employee submits a request. What this basically does is send out a brochure (in PNG format and stored in Google Drive). Somehow, the code does not work. Spent almost the entire day scouring the net for answers, but none helped. I tried the DriveApp.getFileByID method and it worked, but that was just for one file. The attachment depends on the product that the employee selects on the Google form, and that is dynamic.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
function SendBrochure(e) {
    try {


        var email = e.values[1];
        var subject = "ABC Co - Information you requested";
        var msgcc = "test@gmail.com";
        var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
        var cxnm = e.values[2] + " " + e.values[3] + " " + e.values[4];
        var msgl1 = "Greetings from ABC Co, " + cxnm + ".";

        var emailText = "<b>Greetings from ABC Co, " + cxnm + ". </b> <p>With reference to your conversation     
    with us and your request for information, please find attached herein the same.</p> <p> Should you 
    require further assistance, please contact the undersigned, or refer to the brochure for pertinent   
    site contact details.</p> <p>We appreciate your interest and look forward to your visit soon.</p> 
    <p> Thanks and regards, <br><b>ABC Co</b><br>Tel: +1 202 555 1212<br>Web: 
    www.abc.com </p>";

        var brochurename = e.values[5]; //gets file name from form (already filled in - for e.g f_1.png)

        var brochure1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName(brochurename);

        GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, msgl1, {
            name: 'ABC Co',
            attachments: [brochure1.next()],
            htmlBody: emailText,
            from: aliases[1]
        });


        GmailApp.sendEmail(msgcc, "Email sent!", "Your email request to " + email + " has been completed successfully at " + e.values[0], {
            'from': aliases[1]
        });


    } catch (e) {
        Logger.log(e.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try getting the image as a blob with the right mime type, see [doc here][1],

in your code it would become :

```
...
attachments: [brochure1.next().getAs('image/png')],
...
```

PS : didn't have the opportunity to test this, please let us know it it does work. [1]: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file?hl=fr-FR#getAs%28String%29

---

**EDIT** : here is a new version of your code that works, just change the image file names to suit your case.

I wrote a test function to be able to test without form submission.

```
function test(){
  var par = {};
  par['values']={};
  par.values[0]=new Date();
  par.values[1]='xxxxxxx@gmail.com';
  par.values[2]='xxxxx';
  par.values[3]='yyyyy';
  par.values[4]='zzzzz';
  par.values[5]='LOGO.jpg';// just for test I took a file I had in my drive
  SendBrochure(par);
}

function SendBrochure(e) {
  Logger.clear();
  var email = e.values[1];
  var subject = "ABC Co - Information you requested";
  var msgcc = "yyyyyyyy@gmail.com";
  var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
  var cxnm = e.values[2] + " " + e.values[3] + " " + e.values[4];
  var msgl1 = "Greetings from ABC Co, " + cxnm + ".";

  var emailText = "<b>Greetings from ABC Co, " + cxnm + ". </b> <p>With reference to your conversation "+    
    "with us and your request for information, please find attached herein the same.</p> <p> Should you "+
      "require further assistance, please contact the undersigned, or refer to the brochure for pertinent "+  
        "site contact details.</p> <p>We appreciate your interest and look forward to your visit soon.</p>"+ 
          "<p> Thanks and regards, <br><b>ABC Co</b><br>Tel: +1 202 555 1212<br>Web: www.abc.com </p>";
  var brochurename = e.values[5]; //gets file name from form (already filled in - for e.g f_1.png)
  var brochure = false;
  Logger.log('brochurename = '+brochurename)
  var brochure1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName(brochurename);
  if(brochure1.hasNext()){
    var brochure = brochure1.next().getBlob();// get the blob
    Logger.log('brochure name = '+brochure.getName())
  }else{
    Logger.log("didn't find a file with name = "+brochurename)
  }
  Logger.log('email data = '+email+'  '+subject+'  '+ msgl1)
  if(brochure){
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, msgl1,{attachments:[brochure], htmlBody:emailText});  
    GmailApp.sendEmail(msgcc, "Email sent!", "Your email request to " + email + " has been completed successfully at " + e.values[0])   
  }
  GmailApp.sendEmail(msgcc, "Email not sent!", "Your email request to " + email + " has not been sent because of an invalid attachment\nSee Log below : \n\n"+Logger.getLog());   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I tried the same, but it gave me the following error: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end. I also put it into a separate file and ran - but it threw the same error. Is there anyway I can include the picture inline from Google Drive? Thanks. Much appreciated.

Comment: this error is different, it means that it didn't find a file with the required name. To prevent that use a condition like  if(brochure1.hasNext()){...

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out.. somehow. I used driveapp.getfilebyid. Now the problem is that it won't attach the appropriate file. my code: `code` var proj = e.values[5];
    
    if(proj = "RT.pdf"){
    var brochurename = "0B4F9WhlpOz3dZFR0WjJ1NUttWGM";
  } if(proj = "RA.pdf"){
      var brochurename = "0B4F9WhlpOz3dakRyTWtOT1ZCcVE";
    } if(proj = "RG.pdf"){
      var brochurename = "0B4F9WhlpOz3dYW5STGMybG5SdzQ";
    } if(proj = "RI.pdf"){
      var brochurename = "0B4F9WhlpOz3dQkZnbVdCWlh2NEU";
    } if(proj = "WC.pdf"){
      var brochurename = "0B4F9WhlpOz3dRndwazBaaFhwRDA";
    } `code`

Comment: It won't attach the appropriate file. Instead, it just does it at random. Could you please help me with the if / else statements? Thanks!

Comment: sorry for the delay, I'm meeting some ISP issues right now... very poor connection and no access to my Google drive :-/

Comment: No problem. I can wait. :-)

Comment: heheh.. silly me.. i forgot that the 'equals to' operator in jscript is '==' and not just '='. Thanks a ton @Serge insas! I'm calling it a day!

Comment: Thanks again Serge. Worked like a charm!